# Visit every couple of element of a generic List in Java only once

Tags: java, list, listiterator

I have a List in Java, and I would like to exploit a visit for every couple of element only once. For example if I had an Array I would have done something like:

```
O[] x = ...;
for(int i = 0; i<x.length; i++){
     for(int j=i+1; j<x.length;j++){
          someOperation(x[i],x[j]);
     }
}
```

The problem is that I have a List (and we suppose to don't know if the List is an ArrayList or a LinkedList).
In order to have the same complexity as the case listed before, I would write in pseudo-code, something like:

```
 ListIterator<O> it1 = list.listIterator();
 while(it1.hasNext()){
      O x = it1.next();
      it2 = it1.clone();   //it2 have the same "status" of it1, but it is a different object in memory
      while(it2.hasNext()){
           y= it.next();
           someOperation(x,y);
      }
 }
```

As far as I know we don't have anything like it1.clone(). The only way to do a similar stuff it is more or less:

```
 int i = it1.nextIndex();
 it2 = list.listIterator(i);
```

but, as far as I know,

```
 list.listIterator(i);
```

could have a complexity of O(n) - in the case of a LinkedList, and this is absolutely avoidable in other languages. On the other side, implementing the same algorithm using a random access (like list.get(i)), would be even worst.
What is the correct way to write the code assuming that the list is a LinkedList?

Comment: You can copy the `LinkedList` to an `ArrayList` just at the beginning, which is O(n). Then do your pair operation with it. It's an extra O(n) which doesn't increase complexity and some extra space.

Comment: What if you went the other direction. Create a new list and accumulate elements as you go.

Comment: @BoristheSpider you're right, I missed that part of the question.

Comment: @matt I like also your approach. I think it is even better than your answer :) in the first time in fact I would have to copy the whole list and then remove the elements, while in this approach we just create the list during the visiting. Without any overload..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just swap `i` and `j`?

```
List<E> x = ...;
int j = 0;
for (E ej : x) {
    int iMax = j++;
    int i = 0;
    for (E ei : x) {
        if (i++ >= iMax)
            break;
        someOperation(ei, ej);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is in my opinion the most efficient solution till now, and even the simpler one: doesn't involve iterator, and doesn't require extra memory :) Thanks

Comment: @Samuele you're welcome. Btw, iterator is involved implicitly inside "for-each" loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you can modify the list:

```
Iterator<Items> things = list.iterator();

while(things.hasNext()){
    Item item = things.next();
    things.remove();
    Iterator<Item> others = list.iterator();
    while(others.hasNext()){
        //... do stuff;
    }
}
```

If the order doesn't matter you can build a new List.

```
List<Item> others = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
for(Item item: list){
    for(Item other: others){
        // do stuff
    }
    others.add(item);
}
```

Comment: I think that this is the best way to solve the problem, even if before doing this I must copy the list. I wounder why we don't have something like iterator.clone(). Will be much easier in my opinion.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I don't agree with you,  in fact matt creates the second Iterator after the removing operation

Comment: @BoristheSpider I thought that about using a for each, but I wasn't sure. The two iterators [works](http://ideone.com/k5WEq2). Although, modifying the list might add more overhead than the list iterator solution.

Comment: @matt yes, it does seem to work - but it would obviously blow up if `others` modified the `list`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best solution would be to use `list.listIterator(i)` anyway.

In the case of LinkedList this is O(n), but the complexity of your algorithm would be still O(n^2). In terms of Big-Oh, it wouldn't change anything!

Cheers

Comment: You re right, in term of Big-O nothing changes, but your code  - in case of a linked list - will take more or less the double of the time, that in my own opinion, is bad.